# R: how to make sure the fitted values of a glm model are binary

Tags: r, glm

```
 a = rnorm(10)
 b = rnorm(10)
 c = rnorm(10)
 status = c(rep(0, 5), rep(1, 5))
 status = as.factor(status)
 dat = data.frame(a, b, c, status)
 mod = glm(status~., dat, family = "binomial")
```

I have a dataset, and my response variable is a binary variable, i.e. 0 for control and 1 for case. When I call `mod$fit` to look at the fitted values, they are not binary. They are numeric instead. How can I make sure that the fitted values are binary? I tried `as.factor(status)`, but that doesn't work. I've also tried `predict(mod, test = data.frame(e = rnorm(10), f = rnorm(10), g = rnorm(10)), type = "response")` but that doesn't give me binary responses, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want binary responses, you need to decide on a cutoff value -- this is not at all trivial (there is a whole statistical literature about ROC [receiver-operator curves] and the tradeoff between sensitivity and specificity), but a reasonable default option is to choose 0.5.

Data:

```
 dat <- data.frame(a = rnorm(10),
                  b = rnorm(10),
                  c = rnorm(10),
                  status = factor(rep(0:1, each=5)))
 mod <- glm(status~., dat, family = "binomial")
```

Dichotomizing:

```
 f <- fitted(mod) ## or predict(mod,type="response")
 bf <- ifelse(f<0.5,0,1)  ## or as.numeric(f<0.5)
```

If you have more questions about the statistical/non-programming aspects, it might be best to ask on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).